# Multi Schemas EntityFrameWork Switching Dynamic not working C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

,We are working on an application that uses multiple Schemas. 1 Schema per tenant/customer.

We are using EntityFramework. I created a way to pass down the customer name to my DBcontext.

But for some reason it will reminder the first schema after every call.

My PostgresContext.CS

```
public PostgresContext(DbContextOptions<PostgresContext> options, iState state, ConnectionStringSettings connectSettings)
        : base(options)
    {
        _state = state;
        schemaName = _state.GetSchema();
        conString = connectSettings.ConnectionString;
        
    }
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connectionString: conString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .HasPostgresExtension("fuzzystrmatch")
            .HasPostgresExtension("postgis")
            .HasPostgresExtension("tiger", "postgis_tiger_geocoder")
            .HasPostgresExtension("topology", "postgis_topology");

        modelBuilder.Entity<applicatie_configuration>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.id).HasName("applicatie_configuration_pkey");
            entity.ToTable("applicatie_configuration", schemaName);
            entity.Property(e => e.customer_name).HasMaxLength(250);
            entity.Property(e => e.json_translate_property).HasMaxLength(200);
            entity.Property(e => e.name).HasMaxLength(200);
        });
    }
    //The rest is cut. Since its like 400lines of modelBuilder.Entity...
```

The point I add the context to my services

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var connectString = configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString");
        
        services.AddDbContext<PostgresContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseNpgsql(connectString);
            
        },ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        
        return services;
```

Comment: It is normal behaviour. EF calls `OnModelCreating` only once per `DbContext` class type. So, if you want do change schema on the fly, you have to find better place.

Comment: GitHub issue for that: [Allow model building outside of OnModelCreating](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11738) - here you can find solution via `UseModel`.

Comment: Is there a better way do it then via the UseModel/ModelBuilder.

The best solution would be DBcontext.ChangeSchema but that doesn't exist.

I just tried it via this way since it was the only location I could find to do something with Schemas.

Comment: As I know how EF Core works, you have only one option:  `UseModel()`. EF Core works with immutable Model definition. For each schema you have to define DbContextOptions and instantiate DbContext using these options.